# Unable to login after changing WordPress site url

Tags: urls

I changed my live WordPress site URL from `https://mywebsite.com` to `localhost/myproject` just for testing purpose. But Now I am unable to login to my website again because after I login, it redirects me to `https://localhost/myproject/wp-login.php.` and there's the error `This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.`

How can I change the URL back to normal?

Comment: If u can access the data base from there you can change the `site url` and `home url` in `wp_options`

Comment: That's ok, I'm done!. I add these lines to functions.php "update_option('siteurl','http://mywebsite.com');
update_option('home','http://mywebsite.com');"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**First method is**

Add the above code in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/myproject');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/myproject');
```

**Second method is**

Comment Plugins one by one and check.

After successfully login update permalink.

Comment: Hello, I've done. Thank you. I add these lines to functions.php "update_option('siteurl','mywebsite.com'); update_option('home','mywebsite.com');" and update the permalink

Comment: But thank you for pointing out update permalink.